# SVG getIntersectionList returns null

Tags: javascript, android, svg, android-browser

In the context of a SVG file, the following JavaScript:

```
var svg = document.rootElement, hitRect, hits;

hitRect = svg.createSVGRect();
hitRect.height = 1;
hitRect.width = 1;
hitRect.y = 100;
hitRect.x = 100;

hits = svg.getIntersectionList(hitRect, null);
```

always assigns `null` to `hits`, regardless if there were any intersections at all (in the case of no intersections, it should've been an empty NodeList).

Has anyone stumbled in to this problem? Is there a known workaround for hit-testing a SVG in Android?

Tested on: Android default browser on Android 4.0.3 (emulator), 4.0.3 (GALAXY Note SC-05D). (Google Chrome works)

**Edit**

I also tried looping through all elements (`document.getElementsByTagName("*")`), testing each one with `svg.checkIntersection`, to no avail. `checkIntersection` just returned `true` for every single element.

Comment: I'd be tempted to put a testing example on a jsfiddle.

Comment: a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ed54Lmus/

Answer (score 4):

I also encounter the problem when test of iOS Safari <= 5.0, same like it's not support SVG 1.1, so after adding following attribute to the svg element, it's no effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <rect id="r1" x="5" y="5" width="40" height="40"/>
   <rect id="r2" x="105" y="105" width="40" height="40"/>
   <rect id="r3" x="5" y="5" width="40" height="40"/>
   <rect id="rr" x="5" y="5" width="400" height="400" fill="red"/>
   <rect id="r4" x="5" y="5" width="40" height="40"/>
   <rect id="r5" x="5" y="5" width="40" height="40"/>
</svg>

<script type="text/javascript">

var isTouch = ('ontouchstart' in window) || ('DocumentTouch' in window && document instanceof DocumentTouch);
var downE = isTouch? 'touchstart' :'mousedown';
var moveE = isTouch? 'touchmove' :'mousemove';
var upE = isTouch? 'touchend' :'mouseup';

window.addEventListener(downE, startTest )
function startTest (evt) {
    setTimeout(function  () {

        var svg=document.querySelector('svg');
        var r = svg.createSVGRect();
        r.x = 20;
        r.y = 20;
        r.width = r.height = 44;
        var getIntersectionList = svg.getIntersectionList(r, null );
        var checkIntersection = svg.checkIntersection( document.querySelector('#r2'), r );
        var elementFromPoint = document.elementFromPoint(20,20);
        alert("getIntersectionList: "+getIntersectionList);
        alert("checkIntersection: "+checkIntersection);
        alert("elementFromPoint: "+elementFromPoint);

    },1000);

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above test code should alert:

```
getIntersectionList: [object NodeList]
checkIntersection: false
elementFromPoint: [object SVGRectElement]
```

But in iOS Safari <=5.0 and some android it's alert:

```
getIntersectionList: null
checkIntersection: true
elementFromPoint: [object SVGRectElement]
```

So, if you want to get better compatibility, only rely on the method:

```
var el = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
```

it's get topmost element under the point (x,y), even support IE 5.5

You can test 5 points in a small rect area(center, 4 corner) (or more points), to workaround this.